# Sending Character Zero "\0" Over Binary Socket In Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, sockets

This code doesn't send the trailing null byte.  How do I send the trailing null?

```
Socket.writeUTFBytes('Hello World');
Socket.flush();
```

Thanks in advance.  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `writeByte`.

```
socket.writeUTFBytes('Hello World');
socket.writeByte(0);
socket.flush();
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain how to attach it to the end of a string literal. But you can always do:

```
Socket.writeByte(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
Socket.writeUTFBytes('Hello World\0');
Socket.flush();
```